# Importance of _metadata file when using Dask on a partitioned dateset

Tags: python, dask

I have a simple understanding that information about files in a parquet dataset can be placed into the `_metadata` file and used to [give a more efficient creation of a parquet Dataset](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#writing-metadata-and-common-medata-files). However, I was experiencing performance issues when using Dask `to_parquet` with `append=True` and `write_metadata_file=True`, my full command is below. (I still haven't fully understood what was happening but my memory would spike, just before the `to_parquet` was split off to the workers). I, therefore, decided to set `write_metadata_file=False` and continue without a `_metadata` file at all, removing the previously created `_metadata` file.

I have found that the problem went away, and the `to_parquet` is no slower, if anything I saved time not having to write the `_metadata` file each time.

In addition at a glance, when I `read_parquet` the files, it also appears not having the `_metadata` file is not causing poor performance as I expected.

I have chosen to partition when appending and wonder if this is the reason that the `_metadata` file is not so important, or is this incorrect? Is there obvious situations when `_metadata` file are important and when they are not?

**Simple example of code**

```
dd.to_parquet(df,
              engine='fastparquet',
              path=uri, storage_options=dl.storage_options,
              partition_on=['A', 'B', 'C'],
              append=True,
              ignore_divisions=True,
              write_metadata_file=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metadata file provides three potentially useful things:

- the file names of all of the constituent partitions
- offsets within each of those files for the column chunks
- min/max statistics for values within each column chunk
- the schema of the dataset can be read from a _common_metadata file or from any one of the data files.

The first of these is easily found by listing the filesystem, which is fast locally, but could be slow for remote storage if you have thousands of files.

The second is required, but can be read from each data file's footer, in worker tasks and in parallel. Thus, if you don't get them ahead of time, you end up doing more work, but might not notice (especially if each part has many rows). It might end up faster, compared to parsing a huge metadata file in the client.

The third, if not got from the metadata file, can only be got by scanning *all* of the files' metadata footers, which can be painfully slow and done single-threaded in the client. However, if you are not using these stats to filter (gather_statistics=None or False), then you can completely do without.
You will still be able to filter on the partitioning columns without max/min stats.

Finally, and for completeness: why is partitioned append with metadata slow? The single metadata file must be rewritten each time you append, and it first needs to get all of the metadata pieces from each task. I also needs to hold all of the metadata pieces in memory. This could probably be better done, but that is the current implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I got a sense that metadata files really comes into its own when you are doing statistics. Considering I am not and with the current implementation when appending parquet is slowish I think the trade off for not having the metadata file is there.